# Small program to automate a task?

Tags: google-search

Here is a thing. I am from Poland but I'd like to use google.com instead of google.pl. But every time I go to google.com it redirects me to polish version of the site. I've already tried adding /ncr at the end of the address but it doesn't work. To be able to use the english version of google I have to type something into the search bar, click on the wheel on the right site --> search setting --> languages and change it to wanted language, english in this case. I thought I could write a program to make it simpler. What I would like to ask you guys is to give me some suggestions ideas about programming language, tools to use, anything really would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is not a good fit for the site as it is too open-ended.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.de/setprefdomain?prefdom=US&sig=0_Ft2f2VNGqB3slvET2JlWtBPSfco%3D

Add the far right bottom of google.pl, there should be a link to google.com, refering the above one